# How to check if a column is being updated

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

Let's suppose I have an instruction that does the following:

```
update client set active = 0;
```

Is there any way to do it in Firebird, the same thing as Oracle does ...

```
if updating (active) ...
```

The trigger would only be executed if it had only only updating the "active" column.

I tried that way, but it's not working:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER CLIENT_SYNC FOR CLIENT
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0
as begin   
    IF UPDATE(ACTIVE)   
        new.ACTIVE = NULL;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebird doesn't have anything like `updating`. You need to compare the previous value (in the `old` context variable) with the new value (in the `new` context variable), preferably using [`is distinct from`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-isnotdistinct) to avoid issues with `null`:

```
set term #;
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER CLIENT_SYNC FOR CLIENT
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE POSITION 0
as 
begin   
    IF (old.active is distinct from new.active) then  
        new.ACTIVE = NULL;
end#
set term ;#
```

The update of by setting `new.ACTIVE = null` seems a bit odd in the context, but I assume that is just a placeholder (otherwise `ACTIVE` can never by anything other than `null`).

And be sure to consult the [Firebird documentation on procedural SQL](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql), as the code in your question has several other syntax errors.